# Manipulate ninja forms mail body

Tags: php, ninja-forms

How can I manipulate the ninja forms (3) mail body based on the input of the user?

**example:**

The user fills in the `zipcode` field and I wan't to add data to the mail body of the closest store.

The only useful filter I've found is "`ninja_forms_submit_data`". But it returns only field ID's and the user input.

What I need is a field key so I can use that as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a filter named `ninja_forms_action_email_message` that can be used to customise the email body. Source code is [here](https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms/blob/c7cb0518823581ca6a10a0a9138e5f894214d461/includes/Actions/Email.php#L62).

The filter has three arguments:

1. `$message` This is a (HTML) string of the current email body
2. `$data` Form data (includes data about the form and user submission)
3. `$action_settings` Params for sending the email (to address, etc.)

Example:

```
function custom_email_body_content($message, $data, $action_settings) {
    // You may want to check if the form needs to be customised here
    // $data contains information about the form that was submitted
    // Eg. if ($data[form_id]) === ...

    // Convert the submitted form data to an associative array
    $form_data = array();
    foreach ($data['fields'] as $key => $field) {
        $form_data[$field['key']] = $field['value'];
    }

    // Do something to the email body using the value of $form_data['zipcode']
    // Maybe a str_replace of a token, or generate a new email body from a template

    // Return the modified HTML email body
    return $message;
}

add_filter('ninja_forms_action_email_message', 'custom_email_body_content', 10, 3);
```

Comment: @GuilhermeRossato You can put in your child theme functions.php file